# How to pass a hash as a query with "OR-join"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, conditional-statements

I have a hash with booleans

```
({"u25" => true, "f26t49" => true, "o50" => true, ..});
```

all in all there are 19 booleans and I want to check these with a table in my db and get those data sets, how have at least one match. I had try it with

"Model.all(:conditions => hash)" or "Model.where(hash)"

but there I get the query

"..u25 == true AND f26t49 == true AND o50 == true..."

but I need something like this:

"..u25 == true OR f26t49 == true..."

I hope you could help me!

ADDITION:

I tryed to make a workaround and generate a query string out of the hash. If i write this string directly (m = Model.where("u25 == 't'")) it works but if I pass a varaible

```
@query = '"u25 == ' + "'t'" + '"'

m = Model.where(@query)
```

than m is nil!

Comment: Are those conditions always true? If they are, then you should only need an array like [u25, f26t49, ...], right?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your workaround put you in the right direction. Here's what I would do:

```
# model.rb
def self.search_with_conditions(hash)
  query = hash.map{|k,v| "#{k} == #{v}"}.join(' OR ')
  where(query)
end
```

And then in your controller, simply call:

```
m = Model.search_with_conditions(hash)
```

Sidenote: This might work for some DBs and not for others as some use 1 as the value for true. Also, I didn't have time to try this so I may be missing some quotation marks in that condition. I think it could be `'#{v}'`.

EDIT: After learning a little bit more about Rails, I must add a disclaimer here:

**If the strings k or v are part of some user input, this approach is susceptible to SQL injection. Use this method with care.**

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's not perfekt but it works! I changed the #{v} into 't' for sqlite respectively '1' for mysql (haven't test it for mysql yet)

Comment: If you are always checking if those conditions are true, then you should probably use an array instead of a hash. And since you are only using the keys of the hash, and not the values, you can substitute `|k,v|` for `|k|`. Works the same in this case. And accept my answer when you can.